# How to fix 405 error with ajax call to controller in .net core

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core

I have a controller in a .Net core 2.2 application to which I am trying to place an ajax PUT call from within the same application.  I get back a 405 error and note that in the response header, it says  access-control-allow-origin: *
allow: GET, POST.  How can I get my controller to allow PUT and DELETE requests - which I think is the problem?  Or if that's not the problem, what should I do?

Comment: What does your `AddCors` look like?

Comment: Share us your `Startup.cs` and Controller action.

Comment: Following is in Configure services:

```services.AddCors(c =>
            {
                c.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin", options => options.AllowAnyOrigin());
            });``` 

and in Configure -  

```app.UseCors(options => options.AllowAnyOrigin());```

Comment: Controller:

```public async Task<IActionResult> PutLearningTask(LearningTask learningTask)
        {
            if (learningTask.Id != learningTask.Id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _context.Entry(learningTask).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {...handle... }

            return NoContent();```
        }

Comment: Sorry - controller is```[HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutLearningTask(int id, LearningTask learningTask)
        {
            if (id != learningTask.Id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _context.Entry(learningTask).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {...handle...
            }

            return NoContent();
        } ```